# Error in string format

Tags: java, string, format

I have a method that prints out the total price as a double after calculating the charge and adding a fee to it.

```
public static String printWarehouseCharge(Warehouse w[])
{
    String wc = "";     
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        // method that calculates charge and returns a double
        double warehouseCharge = w[i].calculateWarehouseCharge();
        //here the calculateTransportFee method adds a fee and returns the total to be printed
        wc = wc+String.format("$%,.2f",  w[i].calculateTransportFee(warehouseCharge) +"\n");
    }
    return wc;
}
```

Unfortunately I keep getting a format error: `IllegalFormatConversionException`.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: simply your `calculateTransportFee` method do not return a correct float.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are trying to add a number with a string in the below line. 
`w[i].calculateTransportFee(warehouseCharge) +"\n"`

what is returned from w[i].calculateTransportFee(warehouseCharge) is a number either float or double and you are addin git it to `\n`.

This should work for you...

`wc = wc+String.format("$%,.2f",  w[i].calculateTransportFee(warehouseCharge)) +"\n";`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is appending `+"\n"` with `double` at `String.format` which is a  `IllegalFormatConversionException`

```
wc = wc+String.format("$%,.2f", 
    w[i].calculateTransportFee(warehouseCharge)); // Remove "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might get IllegalFormatConversionException when the argument corresponding to the format specifier is of an incompatible type. In your code you specified that the method 'format' should expect floating point number. You provided not *'warehouseCharge'* , but the string *'warehouseCharge + "\n"'*. When adding string and a number, the result is always string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is argument to the `String.format` method. Your **second** argument is expected to be `double/float` but it is actually `String` due to **concantenation**

```
wc = wc+String.format("$%,.2f",  w[i].calculateTransportFee(warehouseCharge) +"\n");
                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^
                                                        Here is the error because the 2nd argument gets converted into String
```

Try this

```
 wc = wc+String.format("$%,.2f",  w[i].calculateTransportFee(warehouseCharge));
 wc+= "\n";
```